# How can I open an editor gutter's inline diff peek view in VS Code with keyboard shortcut?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-git

In VS Code there's information in the gutter regarding the git status of each line, that looks like so:
[image]
If you click in the gutter, this expands a menu that shows the diff locally, like so:
[image]

Is there any way to open the previous menu without clicking on it, and instead using a keyboard shortcut in the line where the cursor is located?

There are shortcuts to cycle through the different changes, but I want something that would open up this menu on the specific line, not something that would force me to circle around the document to end up in the place I was originally.
I've searched in the settings, online documentation and forums and came out empty handed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to check / add shortcuts for these commands:

```
editor.action.dirtydiff.next - Alt+F3
editor.action.dirtydiff.previous - Shift+Alt+F3
```

These are the default keybinds but you can modify.